# Ways to speed up Polygonizing of rasters/orthophotos (binary)?

Tags: qgis, raster, geotiff-tiff, area, polygonize

From a orthophoto of the Wadden Sea, I want to create a polygon from a class of this TIFF/raster (binary) representing an oyster reef, calculate the area of the reef and form a polygon around the reef for further processing.

But since polygonizing this raster takes already so many hours I don't know what I can do.

Is there any way to speed up the process or decrease the size/information of the raster? Or other ideas? Should I decrease the original resolution of the orthophoto?

Size of the TIFF is 3.9 GB and pixel size is 1.86e-7,-1.87e-7

[image]

QGIS version: 3.16.4-Hannover
Ubuntu 18.04
64 GB Ram
Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-9900K CPU @ 3.60GHz
M.2-PCIe-NVMe-SSD-Disk, 512 GB

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to specify the type of disk (SSD/HDD), and if HDD, the RPM and seek time.

Comment: Your GDAL is very old (screenshot shows 2.2.3, I wonder if it is possible). The newest GDAL version has an improved polygonizing algorithm. I would indeed consider what is the resolution that is really needed and downsample the raster if possible. Also if it is possible to decrease the number of different raster values, ideally into reef/not reef pixels, it would simplify pologonizing.